# Detecting triple taps on the body of android phones

Tags: android, accelerometer

I've been searching for algorithms for detecting when an android phone is tapped 3 times using the accelerometer. Tried looking at tutorials on how the accelerometer works but the closest I could get to was detecting when the phone is shaked. 
I would like to know if there's a better approach for doing tap detections other than using an accelerometer sensor.
How to do tap detections in android?

Comment: http://mylifewithandroid.blogspot.in/2013/06/tap-detection-supported-by-gyroscope.html this could help you to understand

Comment: Can you please be a bit precise i.e what do you want to do after detecting triple taps. There may be a possible workaround for it.

Comment: thanks @SivakumarS the link looks like what I'm searching for. I'll check it out.

Comment: @nimi0112 I'll like my application to use the taps detected as a trigger to do something. Unfortunately, that's how specific I can get.